On the "idea" of calculus of variations to an inequality in the $L^p$ norm

Let C be a constant, satisfying $$\forall p \in [1,\infty),\, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n,\text{s.t.}\Vert x\Vert_p=\Vert y\Vert_p ,\,\text{and}\, \forall \theta \in [0,1], \, \\\Vert x-y\Vert_p\leq C\Vert \theta x-(1-\theta)y\Vert_p. $$ Find the minimum of C.

To clarify: $$\Vert x\Vert_p:=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{\frac1p},\text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$$
Above all, the answer is $4$ but I do not know why, and it is said that we need some technique in fuctional-analysis to solve the problem.
Anyway, I first tried the case for $p=2$, and this is quite easy: We can substitute $-y$ for $y$ to get $$\Vert x+y\Vert_p\leq C\Vert \theta x+(1-\theta)y\Vert_p,$$ and this is  quite clear in geometry. So $C_p=2$ when $p=2.$
When it comes to other cases, I found it hard to deal with the $\dfrac{1}{p}$ on the exponent. Someone told me we need some ideas from calculus of variations. I can only expand the inequality:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+y_i)^p \leq C^p \times\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\theta x_i +(1-\theta)y_i)^p\right)$$
However, because $x,y$ are not even continuous, I cannot find a proper way to use calculus of variations. Also, multiplying the both side of the inequality by $\dfrac{d}{d\theta}$ just make inequality more complicated.
How to construct $p$ to show the minimum is $4$ and to prove it? (Someone said that $C_p=4$ where $p=4$.)

This is not related to an $L^p$ (function) space nor calculus of variations. Have you tried setting up a Lagrange multiplier and differentiating as in standard multivarible calculus?

I just learned how to use calculus of variations on some simple examples but I do not learn functional analysis systematically. Anyway this problem is from a test for high school students (that learned basic calculus and linear algebra), and as what I have said, it just used the "idea" of calculus of variations even though I do not know what is the relationship between them. I misuderstood $L^p$ space, maybe I should call it $L^p$-norm instead.

Clearly we need only to consider the case which $\theta\leq\dfrac12$:
$$\\\Vert x-y\Vert_p\leq \dfrac{1}{1-\theta}\Vert \theta x-(1-\theta)y\Vert_p+\dfrac{1-2\theta}{1-\theta}\Vert  x\Vert_p=\dfrac{1}{1-\theta}\Vert \theta x-(1-\theta)y\Vert_p+\dfrac{1}{1-\theta}(-\theta\Vert  x\Vert_p+(1-\theta)\Vert  x\Vert_p)=\dfrac{1}{1-\theta}\Vert \theta x-(1-\theta)y\Vert_p+\dfrac{1}{1-\theta}(-\theta\Vert  x\Vert_p+(1-\theta)\Vert  y\Vert_p)\leq\dfrac{1}{1-\theta}\Vert \theta x-(1-\theta)y\Vert_p+\dfrac{1}{1-\theta}(\Vert -\theta x+(1-\theta) y\Vert_p)=\frac{2}{1-\theta}\Vert \theta x-(1-\theta)y\Vert_p\leq4\Vert \theta x-(1-\theta)y\Vert_p,$$
so $C\leq4$, and we pick $n=2,p=1,x=(1/4,0),y=(1/4-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and let $\epsilon \to 0$ to get $C=4$.
